# MS Analysis Services + IIS - configuration/connection issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, sql-server-2008, sql-server, olap

(I am not a professional windows server admin and its my first time dabbling with analysis services.)

I am trying to get the Analysis Services up and running such that I can fire MDX queries via XMLA.

Here is what I have done so far (on a standard "windows 2008 with sql" ec2 instance. IIS 6.1)-

- Got the sample AdventureWorks cube up and running. I can locally fire MDX queries and it works.
- Followed [this link](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/mglaser/archive/2008/08/15/configuring-http-access-to-sql-server-2008-analysis-services-on-microsoft-windows-server-2008.aspx) to get HTTP access to Analysis Services. (The only deviation is that in my case I see only rows 1,2,5 from figure 11)
- Can successfully connect to http://localhost/olap/msmdpump.dll from SQL Server management studio and fire XMLA EXECUTE commands with basic MDX queries.

Problem

- I am unable to to access this from a host other than localhost. I can access http://servername just fine (default IIS page) but http://servername/olap/msmdpump.dll gives me a 500 from any host other than the server itself. (I get the expected soap envelope with soap fault from a browser on localhost)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/solution you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to do this:

http://codesnob.wordpress.com/2009/06/03/remote-error-messages-iis/

The DLL will be sending an HTTP 500 error header to IIS hoping that it will return that to the client, however, IIS by default is set to only show errors to localhost requests so it replaces the SOAP error page with its own. Its a security feature, so I would only do it for the site that you have configured the OLAP HTTP handler on, unless its a development/non-production/non-web-facing server.

Comment: you are right! it was in fact working as expected all this time. thank you.